How to create a file in a volume inline in Argo Workflow step
Currently, if I wanted to put several files into a volume inline, I would execute something like this:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: prepare-files-on-volume
  namespace: argo-workflows
spec:
  templates:
  - name: prepare-files-on-volume
    script:
      volumeMounts:
      - name: workdir
        mountPath: /mnt/app
      image: node:18
      command: [sh]
      source: |
        #!/bin/sh

        mkdir -p /mnt/app

        cat <<EOF > /mnt/app/my-file.js
        This is the content of my file. Imagine it's very long with many special chars!
        EOF

        cat <<EOF > /mnt/app/my-file-2.js
        This is the content of my second file. Imagine it's very long as well!
        EOF        

This method however forces me to escape special chars and doesn't allow me to just copy paste a file as is and expect to see it exactly the same way in the volume. I've managed to do so while escaping some special characters, but I could have missed something and it becomes difficult to manage.
Does anyone know of a more consistent method to push the contents of a file into a volume  in Argo Workflows inline?
I would rather avoid using secrets or configmaps, since I want the file contents to live in the same YAML as my other Workflow steps.

Node and sh handle special characters differently typically requiring escaping or template literals to handle special characters. Other images like Ubuntu or Alpine which utilize bash or ash do not require escaping for special characters. Node's shell is more minimalistic with fewer capabilities in comparison to bash or ash, especially when it comes to handling special characters in strings.
Here is a basic functional example using Ubuntu that pushes the contents of a file into a volume in Argo Workflows inline:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: prepare-files-on-volume
  namespace: argo-workflows
spec:
  templates:
    - name: prepare-files-on-volume
      inputs: {}
      outputs: {}
      metadata: {}
      script:
        name: ""
        image: ubuntu:latest
        command:
          - bash
          - "-c"
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workdir
            mountPath: /mnt/app
        source: >
          #!/bin/bash

          echo "First file including special characters: \$ \` \"
          ' \\ # & * ( ) < > ~ | { } [] ; :" > /mnt/app/file1.js


          echo "Second file with: @ % ^ + = ? !, special character patterns:
          {{ }} [[ ]] \\$\\#\\* - \`~!@#\$%^&*()_-+={[}]|\\:;\"'<,>.?/ and
          Unicode: ✅  ⚙️ ☑️ " > /mnt/app/file2.js


          cat /mnt/app/file1.js /mnt/app/file2.js

          ls /mnt/app
  entrypoint: prepare-files-on-volume
  arguments: {}
  volumes:
    - name: workdir
      emptyDir: {}

References:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-the-bash/1565923472/ch01s09.html
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html

